# Hacker keyboard 5 row compact layout - where is the euro sign?

Tags: keyboard

I've been using the hacker keyboard for ages, and with a bigger screen, I started to use the 5 row compact layout - the US international layout that is used for normal keyboards on laptops and desktops.

My problem: where is the € or euro sign?

[image: Android Hacker Keyboard - 5 row compact]

Comment: Too bad you deleted it, because that could be the answer.

Comment: I uninstalled the keyboard, removing all settings, then reinstalled it. I enabled the 5 row compact layout (US QWERTY only). It looks exactly the same as my screenshot. I think you don't have this keyboard selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have English (India) & English US as languages & keyboard set as 5 row compact layout (US QWERTY only), with the keyboard having default settings with only change being  Popup mini keyboard settings to the last one, `Add Self`

[image]

Press **`Alt`** and letter **`e`**, **together** and in the menu that appears, you see **`€`** at the end as in screenshot (see [video](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZLH8vkZwQ4HNe4fmhSVz4XcX1nHK52M60hk))

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't work for you because of system language, you can try other Popup mini keyboard options

Comment: In theme and settings, I enabled ASCII (labelled alternate keys), I don't think that has any bearing, just clarifying so that you know why keyboard looks slightly different

Comment: Did it not work for you? Curious